# App Store Review Team reject iOS app because using GameKit framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, appstore-approval

I just received the email inform that:

---

PLA 3.3.1

We found that your app uses Game Kit public APIs to change Bluetooth device settings.

Game Kit APIs are provided to assist in the creation of social games. Using these APIs for other purposes, such as changing Bluetooth settings on a device, is not prescribed by Apple and is therefore not in compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

In particular, section 3.3.1 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement specifies:

"Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs"

If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app requires, we encourage you to file an enhancement request or to work with the Apple Developer Technical Support team to explore alternative solutions.

---

Then I checked in my source code, and I didn't see any GameKit framework.
Please let me know how can I do to make sure my app will be approved by App Store Review Team.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth? Are you using any third-party library which uses GameKit?

Comment: Check your third-party libraries especially those about bluetooth.

Comment: Hello, I didn't use GameKit, but I used XCDYouTubeKit (https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit), can you check it help me?Thanks!

Comment: since you are having apple membership its best to check with technical support. i dont think XCDYouTubeKit using GameKit

Comment: XCDYouTubeKit is against the YouTube Terms of Service. The only official way of playing a YouTube video inside an app is with a web view and the iframe player API. Unfortunately, this is very slow and quite ugly, so I wrote this player to give users a better viewing experience.... This is written by XCDYouTubeKit developer.... so because of this your app rejected

Comment: My app play audio from youtube, so I need to use XCDYouTubeKit to get the streaming, I contacted with Apple Technical Support, but they didn't give me any help to resolve this problem. so I don't know how I can fix my issue.

Comment: @Bkillnest Did you ever get the app approved with XCDYouTubeKit?

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma Do you know current status of this - if apps are being accepted or rejected?